# Ember - ConnectOutlet - when does view change from preRender to inDom

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to get my head round the connectOutlet method and when a view that is returned from connectOutet is actually inserted into the DOM.

The view that is created in connectOutlet leaves connectOutlet in the preRender state.

```
connectOutlet: function(name, context) {
  // method body
    view = this.createOutletView(outletName, viewClass);

    if (controller) { set(view, 'controller', controller); }
    set(this, outletName, view);

    return view;
}
```

I've not tracked down where or when the view is inserted into the Dom and the view transitions to the inDom state.

I suspect the runloop is at play and it transitions after the current runloop has finished.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: I believe you can observe the view `state` property and write in the console whenever it changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The run loop is indeed in play here. The run loop processes events by draining an ordered collection of queues. In order, they are: `sync`, `actions`, `render`, `afterRender`, `destroy`, and `timers`. View rendering is where the view is actually inserted into the DOM and it is always scheduled on the `render` queue.

If you have other questions about this, leave a comment, and I will be happy to expand this answer to cover them.